# TestWatcher in junit5

Tags: java, junit5

I can't find any annotation which replace/working the same like TestWatcher.

My goal:
Have 2 functions which do something depend on test result.

- Success? Do something
- Fail? Do something else

Comment: Not there, yet. See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542 for details.

Answer (score 21):

The [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html) API was introduced here:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1393
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/release-notes/

Use it as follows:

1. Implement `TestWatcher` class (org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher)
2. Add `@ExtendWith(<Your class>.class)` to your tests classes (I personally use a base test class which I extend in every test) (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)

TestWatcher provides you with the following methods to *do something* on test abort, failed, success and disabled:

- `testAborted​(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause)`
- `testDisabled​(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason)`
- `testFailed​(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause)`
- `testSuccessful​(ExtensionContext context)`

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html

Sample TestWatcher implementation:

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher;

public class MyTestWatcher implements TestWatcher {
    @Override
    public void testAborted(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Optional<String> optional) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you just put this on your tests:

```
@ExtendWith(MyTestWatcher.class)
public class TestSomethingSomething {
...
```

Comment: How to access test data in a TestWatcher?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `AfterTestExecutionCallback`:

```java
public class SomeTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    private final AfterTestExecutionCallback afterTest = context -> {
        final Optional<Throwable> exception = context.getExecutionException();
// if you need method name:
//      final Method method = context.getRequiredTestMethod();
// one method for error/success:
//      after(method, exception);
// or if(exception.isPresent()){}else{})
        exception.ifPresentOrElse(this::onError, this::onSuccess);
    };

    private void onSuccess() {
// Success? Do something
    }

    private void onError(Throwable throwable1) {
// Fail? Do something else
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
// put tests here or in a child class
    }

...

}
```