# How to manage failed tests in JUnit5

Tags: webdriver, screenshot, junit5

I'm migrating to JUnit5 and I'd like to know if there is an easy way in JUnit5 to know when a test failed or not, just like we had in JUnit4 with TestWatcher.

I did some research and found similar, but open questions, like this one:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542
Since most of them are quite old, I'm asking just in case there is a recent solution.

The idea is to be able to do a screenshot or add some message into my log. So, is there a listener or extension or something that quickly allows me to manage the webdriver test's failure/pass/skip? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The JUnit5 approach to this feature is to create an extension, here's an example showing the JUnit5 equivalent of JUnit 4's `TestWatcher`: [code](https://github.com/glytching/junit-extensions/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/glytching/junit/extension/watcher/WatcherExtension.java), [docs](https://github.com/glytching/junit-extensions/blob/master)/docs/watcher.md). Disclaimer: I'm the author of the extensions library which contains this watcher implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, thanks glytching.
It was harder than I expected, but finally made it. As you pointed me, we need to create an external class (e.g. `WatcherExtension`) implementing `BeforeTestExecutionCallback` and `AfterTestExecutionCallback` and then **evaluate the exceptions using the context given by the extension**.
In this class we can add something like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
    Method testMethod = extensionContext.getRequiredTestMethod();
    Boolean testFailed = extensionContext.getExecutionException().isPresent();
    if (testFailed) {
        if (!TESTDATA.excluded.contains(testMethod.getName())) {
            takeScreenshot(testMethod);
            logErrorMessage("Test " + testMethod.getName() + " failed on " + getAppVersion() + " using " + TESTDATA.browser);
        } else {
            logInfoMessage("Test " + testMethod.getName() + " was skipped on " + getAppVersion() + " using " + TESTDATA.browser);
        }
    } else {
        logInfoMessage(testMethod.getName() + " was successfully executed on " + getAppVersion() + " using " + TESTDATA.browser);
    }
```

Finally, you need to add this annotation to your test classes:

```
@ExtendWith(WatcherExtension.class)
public class MyTest extends TestFactory {
    @Test
    public void testMyTest() { //whatever  }
}
```

Personally, I think this is something really basic and should be directly implemented by JUnit5 in future versions.
Thanks!

Comment: FYI: there is in fact active work being done to implement something similar in JUnit Jupiter: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1393

Comment: Thanks Sam! it's really good to know that you are behind this issue. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks again for your great work.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690217/5360885 for a version using the latest implementation of JUnit5.