# How to run code after test failure in JUnit5?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

How can I run a function or a wrap-up code after a test failed in JUnit 5?

Comment: look at [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037406/testwatcher-in-junit5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html) in JUnit 5. On JUnit 4 however, you can use [ErrorCollector](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690217/5838252) brilliantly provides a solution to the problem.

Comment: TestWatcher link no longer working: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html